# Javascript array of functions: Pass each function as parameter to another function

Tags: javascript

I have a usercase where I get an array of functions from backend something like:

```
var arr = [A(){}, B(){}, C(){}];
```

Now I need a way to execute them such that each function in the array is passed as a parameter to another function in the array.

```
A(B(C()));
```

Comment: `arr.reduceRight((p, c) => c(p), undefined);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how you managed to get the functions from the back-end, but it doesn't matter for your question, so here goes your answer:

```
var arr = [A(){}, B(){}, C(){}];

var value = arr[arr.length - 1]();

for (var i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
 value = arr[i](value);
}

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to execute consecutive calls to a list of functions.

**Update:** As ASDFGerte suggests, you can use `reduceRight` instead of `reduce` to reverse the function execution flow.

```js
const text = 'That will be 3.50';
const funcList = [extractNumber, parseNumeric, formatCurrency];

console.log('Parsed:', chainFunctions(funcList, text));
console.log('Parsed:', chainFunctionsReverse(funcList.reverse(), text));

function chainFunctions(funcList, startingValue) {
  return funcList.reduce((result, func) => func(result), startingValue);
}

function chainFunctionsReverse(funcList, startingValue) {
  return funcList.reduceRight((result, func) => func(result), startingValue);
}

function extractNumber(str) {
  return str.match(/\b(\d+(\.\d+)?\b)/)[1];
}

function parseNumeric(numStr) {
  return parseFloat(numStr);
}

function formatCurrency(num) {
  return `$${num.toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```